# How to assign class based on if Drupal region is used?

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

In a Drupal 7 theme, how do I assign a class name to a region if it is used or not? I need three conditions for the region in question for my Drupal theme. There are three content regions: sidebar_first, content and sidebar_second. The code for it is below:

```
                    <?php if ($page['sidebar_first']): ?>
                    <div id="sidebar-first" class="column sidebar">
                        <div class="section">
                            <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>

                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div id="content" class="column">
                        <div class="section">
                            <?php if ($page['highlighted']): ?>
                            <div id="highlighted">
                                <?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <a id="main-content"></a>

                            <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>

                            <?php if ($title): ?>
                            <h2 class="title" id="page-title">
                                <?php print $title; ?>
                            </h2>

                            <div class="title_sep">
                                <div class="title_sep_left"></div>
                                <div class="title_sep_right"></div>

                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

                            <?php if ($tabs): ?>
                            <div class="tabs">
                                <?php print render($tabs); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php print render($page['help']); ?>

                            <?php if ($action_links): ?>
                            <ul class="action-links">
                                <?php print render($action_links); ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php print render($page['content']); ?>

                            <?php print $feed_icons; ?>

                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <?php if ($page['sidebar_second']): ?>
                    <div id="sidebar-second" class="column sidebar">
                        <div class="section">
                            <?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>

                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

If sidebar_first is on the page, then assign the class name 'twocol_left' to `<div id="content" class="column">`. If sidebar_second is present, then assign the class name 'twocol_right' to `<div id="content" class="column">`. Lastly, if sidebar_first and sidebar_second are present, then assign 'threecol' to `<div id="content" class="column">`.

Could someone please help me with this? Perhaps this would be a simple as adding an if/else for `<div id="content" class="column">` inside the class="column"?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out that in the body tag, it lists if there is one sidebar or two. I can use those class names to then style the content region and other items on the page accordingly.

An example is:

```
<body class="html not-front logged-in two-sidebars page-user page-user- page-user-1 not-front logged-in ftrtop_columns ftrbttm_columns admin-menu" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
```

In this example it lists two-sidebars. If I remove one of the sidebar blocks so that one of the sidebars is no longer used on the page, it will show the class 'one-sidebar' in the body tag.